# How to remove unsafe characters from string for logging in C#

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4, npgsql

ASP.NET MVC4 application writes sql statement to Postgresql database log file using npgsql.

Sql statement is got from ngpsql ErrorSql property.

Sometimes binary data is passed to sql, for example pdf file in binary format. In this case, ErrorSql contains nonoprintable characters. Trying to log this to database using npgsql causes exception

Invalid message format from Postgres.
How to replace and remove unsafe characters from string so that it can safely logged ?

Comment: What would you expect the log to contain when there's a PDF logged? Can't quite imagine what a good entry would contain.

Comment: Show how you log and your sql insert statement (log4net config), we do not have a magic bow which allows us to see your code. If you know somethings is binary, you can use base64 encoding to fit it into a string which can be logged.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I expect that, for example 0 byte appears something like as 0x00 and readable characters are not changed

Comment: You can't pass binary values in an SQL statement without escaping them first. Are you sure this is what's happening?

Comment: Not sure. sql statement parses xml and assumes that input is xml string. I passed pdf file instead of xml to it . This causes exception. In this exception handler code tries to write log file. This causes new exception in npgsql with message `Invalid message format`. This message appears in postgres log file also but statement is not logged in log file. postgres.conf contains setting to log error statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the:

```
Convert.ToBase64String("binary data")
```

Or adapting your logging to accept binary data.

Comment: This makes all string unreadable. How to convert only non-characters in strings, eq 0 byte should replace with 0x00 or something similar